# separate(organize) express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I separated routes for rest api like this.  Is there better way to organize router ? or the way I am doing is fine?

app.js

```
app.use('/api/auth',auth);
```

app/controllers/auth/index.js

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
register = require('./register');
router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    console.log("api/auth");
    res.send('api/auth');
    next();
});
router.use('/register',register);
module.exports = router;
```

app/controllers/auth/register.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    rootPath = require('app-root-path'),
    User = require(rootPath+'/app/models/user');

router.post('/',function(req,res,next){
    console.log("api/auth/register");
    next();
 });
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on swaraj'a answer, you should divide your project files into two folders **lib** and **config**. Please note that I'm giving you a generic structure this should be customised according to your project.

- **Config**

  It should contain all the configuration files for your project.
- **lib**

  It should basically have files like `controller.js`, `routes.js`, `db-ops.js`

`controller.js contains and exports all functions required for your program logic.`

`routes.js contains and exports all the routes`

`db-ops.js intializes db connections and contains functions that define operations on database.`

All these files should be required into your app.js which will reside in your projects root directory.

A typical project structure should look something like this:

```
lib

   -routes.js

   -controller.js

   -db-ops.js

config  

-config.json

app.js
```

Comment: Thank you I do  have scripts , config, and middlewares directories.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `routes.js` which has all the separate routes.
Something like,

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use('/api/route1', require('path/to/route1'));
    app.use('/api/route2', require('path/to/route2'));
};
```

Mount this routes in your main `app.js`.
`require('path/to/routes')(app);`

Shameless plug of an example, https://github.com/swarajgiri/express-bootstrap/blob/master/web/routes.js

Comment: Thank you But I think ur way and my way is pretty similar. Can you explain me why that is better ?

Comment: It's just that it gives you one file where all your routes can be found and it keeps your `app.js` lean.